# Basic if statements not working -- Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
input_score = raw_input("Enter Score: ")
score = float(input_score)

if score >= 0.9 and <= 1.0:
    print "A"

elif score >= 0.8 and < 0.9:
    print "B"

elif score >= 0.7 and < 0.8:
    print "C"

elif score >= 0.6 and < 0.7:
    print "D"

elif score < 0.6 and >= 0.0:
    print "F"

else :
print "Error"
```

I keep getting a message on line 4 saying I have a syntax error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `if score >= 0.9 and <= 1.0:` => `if score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0:`

Answer (score 2):

You can't write in python `if score >= 0.9 and <= 1.0:`, as the score is not compared to 1.0 in your expression, but only to 0.9. You could write instead  `if score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0:`. Python actually allows you to write it in a shorter format, as follows:

```
if 1.0>= score >= 0.9:
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `score` in both of `if score >= 0.9 and score <= 1.0` e.g.  This is being parsed as `if (score >= 0.9) and (score <= 1.0)`--it wouldn't make sense to write `if (score >= 0.9) and (<= 1.0)`, since the second part is a separate expression.